# How to disable spring security for certain resource paths

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am implementing spring security in a spring boot application to perform JWT validation where I have a filter and an AuthenticationManager and an AuthenticationProvider. What I want to do is that I want to disable security for certain resource paths (make them unsecure basically).

What I have tried in my securityConfig class (that extends from WebSecuirtyConfigurerAdapater) is below:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(buildJwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter(),
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable();
        httpSecurity.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
```

What I am trying to do right now is that I want to make all my resource paths to be un-secure,

but the above code doesn't work and my **authenticate** method in my CustomAuthenticationProvider (**that extends from AuthenticationProvider**) get executed every time

Authentication piece gets executed irrespective of using permitAll on every request. I have tried anyRequest too in place of antMatchers:

`httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Override the following method in your class which extends WebSecuirtyConfigurerAdapater:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/unsecurePage");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**try updating  your code in order to allow requests for specific paths as below**

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(buildJwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter(),
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll().and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/exemptedPaths/").permitAll();

httpSecurity.csrf().disable(); 
 httpSecurity.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

}
```